# is it possible to pass parameters between jquery files

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

is it possible to pass parameters between jquery files because I have a function.php page which displays products from my database and a comments box for each product on my products page, the function.php page links to my functions.js file, this file gets the value from the comment box. as previously stated my products are displayed on my products.php page, this page is linked to my products.js file which reloads the page using the below function. when the page is reloaded the value disappears from my text box so I want to be able to retain the value in the text box when the products page is reloaded.

```
    $('#show_products').load('function.php');


    $sql = "SELECT * FROM products";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Name: " . $row["productname"]"
?>
<input type="text" class="products">
<?php
<br>";

    }
```

Comment: Really need a better description of use case. Approach would be totally different if you mean use something from one page after a new page is loaded in browser

Comment: I have a form on one page and when I include the jquery file that i need the form data which is inside the text box is lost because the jquery file refreshes the page

Comment: Define `refresh` ... completely reloads whole page, or ajax loads part of page? Please show some actual code for people to help understand problem better. Issue is far too vague

Comment: it reloads the div where my products are being displayed from the database, I also display a text box for each product so the user can comment on it, the problem I am having is that when the page refreshes the value in the textbox disappears

Comment: Might be better to post the form data and populate the values at server. Still not enough details provided in question and original question is starting to be very different than updates you are adding

Comment: No `name` on those `<input>`. How are you matching what is submitted? Also why are you needing to reload the whole form? Again...not enough detail as to how all this works

Comment: Suggest you completely rewrite the question explaining the whole process

Comment: iv edited my question

Comment: Still not clear at all why you even need to reload this form. Update to question is still not detailed enough for anyone to understand how your page and form work and the code shown isn't valid for a submit-able form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't always recommended, but one way to approach this problem is to use global variables.

First, declare a global namespace in the first file that is loaded:

```
window.myNamespace = {};
```

Then, write to this shared namespace with:

```
window.myNamespace.foo = "bar";
```

...and read from this shared namespace in a separate file with:

```
console.log(window.myNamespace.foo);
```